# Search bar in react works, but experiencing very strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In a component when an input is provided it dispatches the input to a reducer

```
const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
    dispatch(userActions.searchByName(searchTerm));
  }
```

Then the reducer takes that value and tries to filter the array based on that input

```
searchByName: (state, action) => {
      state.search = action.payload;

      let newArray = state.users.filter((user) =>
        user.name.toLowerCase().includes(state.search.toLowerCase())
      );

      state.users = newArray;
    },
```

Then this whole array is displayed in one of the other components. The search bar works to some extent:
When you start typing into the search bar it only starts to work after second input. In console I have noticed that if you type "Timmothy" it will only register "Timmoth" in the state.
Additionaly, if I delete text from the input, the state of the array doesn't update and stays the same even though the input value changes.

So what happens currently is if you start typing in the search bar, it updates the array, but always only registers second to last keystroke. Additionally, if you delete input from the search bar, it doesn't register. The value changes, but the array stays with only few items left.

I have tried to not use the additional variable to store the state and do it like this

```
state.users.filter((user) =>
       user.name.toLowerCase().includes(state.search.toLowerCase())
```

But then absolutely nothing happens. Would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm missing here

EDIT

This is the component that receives that input

```
<input onChange={changeSearchTerm} type="text" value={searchTerm}></input>
```

And the `searchTerm` value is saved in useState - `const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");`

Comment: Please share your search bar component code/JSX as well. What event handler are you using?

Comment: Apologies, I updated the question and added additional info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, it only works after the second input because of this block:

```
const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
    dispatch(userActions.searchByName(searchTerm));
  }
```

State setters like `setSearchTerm` are actually [asynchronous](https://sentry.io/answers/forget-set-state-is-async/). This means that after you call `setSearchTerm`, on the next line the value of `searchTerm` is still the old value.

You can instead do one of the following:

```
const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
    dispatch(userActions.searchByName(e.target.value));
}
```

```
const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value, () => {
      // This callback runs only after state has changed
      dispatch(userActions.searchByName(searchTerm));
    });
}
```

Edit: Sorry I missed that you used useState/functional. You can use `useEffect`:

```
const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
     dispatch(userActions.searchByName(searchTerm));
   }
}, [searchTerm]);
```

This way your dispatch will correctly run whenever searchTerm's value changes for sure.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately, first example still returns the same issues, while the second one returns an error and doesn't work :(

Comment: Could you share the error in the second usage?

Comment: Yes its `tate updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument.`

Comment: @KivDaor Ah gotcha added an edit using useEffect that should work!

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem of input "lagging". However, in the actual array that's been displayed it gets updated when you write in the search bar, however, if you delete the input it doesn't update. Do you have any thoughts why would that be?

Comment: Ah get rid of the of “if searchTerm.length > 0” I only added that condition in case it was a required check but if you remove it, your reducer state should update properly when the input is empty

Comment: Yes, I removed that before for it to work properly. I'm realising that my search functionality works properly when you type, but it doesn't when you delete, because updating the input returns a new array, and on deleting it doesn't go back to the previous state of the array. I can't figure out how to solve that though, do you have an idea?

Comment: Could you please share your full component code then as it’s not clear how you’re rendering things or consuming the array. It’ll help to figure things out. Also are you using the useSelector hook?

Comment: I am almost certain that the issue is how I use the reducers to manage the state. I asked another question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72164352 to better explain it, if you would like to take a look

Comment: I'll take a look at that and answer. I think I know what the issue might be but since you asked the second part of your question in a separate stackoverflow thread, if this answer solved your first part then please consider marking it accepted!

Comment: My apologies, I marked your answer as accepted :) if you could take a look at the other issue, would be much appreciated

Comment: No worries at all! Posted an answer there