# Redux Toolkit, trying to use filter in a reducer function, but it doesn't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a reducer that should filter the array and update its state

```
searchByName: (state, action) => {

      state.users = state.users.filter((user) =>
      user.name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase())
    ); 
    },
```

This is to include a search bar functionality in the SPA. However, this way it only works if I type in the search bar, on using backspace to delete it stops working. I tried reading different docs and resources such as https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#redux-toolkit-example to understand what's happening and modify the code to use `return` but nothing seems to work?

if I use it this way, as was suggested in some answers

```
searchByName: (state, action) => {

      return state.users.filter((user) =>
      user.name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase())
    ); 
    },
```

I get `Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Immer] Immer only supports setting array indices and the 'length' propert` error

Also if I use `map` or `sort` it does work this way, I can't understand why filter doesn't. How can I fix this?

EDIT

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    users: [],
    isLoading: true,
    search: "",
  },
  reducers: {
    usersSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.users = action.payload;
      state.isLoading = false;
    searchByName: (state, action) => {

      return {
        ...state.users,
        users: [...state.users].filter((user) => user.name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase()))
     };

    },
  },
});
```

EDIT 2

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { users, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userActions.searchByName(searchTerm));
    console.log(searchTerm);
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={changeSearchTerm} type="text" value={searchTerm}></input>
    </div>
  );
};
```

EDIT 3

I added the state filteredUsers in slice

```
initialState: {
    users: [],
    filteredUsers: [],
    isLoading: true,
    search: "",
  },
```

Then in the component that is supposed to display the users I changed to

```
const { filteredUsers, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.filteredUsers);
```

And then mapped it

```
{filteredUsers.map((user) => (
            <Users user={user} />
          ))}
```

Comment: you should look into selectors for getting filtered data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A reducer function always returns the full state. [Reducers use Immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) internally to help manage immutability and write good state changing code.

Here's how you should actually return in searchByName:

```
searchByName: (state, action) => {
    // The object you return is the full state object update in your reducer
    return {
       ...state,
       users: [...state.users].filter((user) => user.name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase())
    };
},
```

Edit: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-estrela-b6o5p3?file=/src/index.js

Your actual issue, however, is that you're **overwriting** your `state.users` whenever you search for anything in the input. Because by doing `state.users = state.users.filter(...` or even the way I suggested above: `return {...state, users: state.users.filter...`, you will lose your original users data the moment you start typing anything into the search bar.

Your reducer has no way of going back to the original state of the users list because **it doesn't know what the original state was** as all it had was the `users` array, which is being modified.

Reducer stores should only be used for state-affecting actions. In your case, `searchByName`/a search bar implementation is something you would actually only want to do inside your component where the search bar + filtered users is being used.

**Solution 1: Get rid of the searchByName user action and do it directly within your component**

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { users, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState(users);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredUsers(users.filter((user) => user.name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase());
    
  }, [searchTerm]);

  // Just for debug/logging purposes to see your filteredUsers
  useEffect(() => {console.log(filteredUsers)}, [filteredUsers]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={changeSearchTerm} type="text" value={searchTerm}></input>
    </div>
  );
```

**Solution 2: If you want to use filteredUsers in other components/across your app, add a separate field to your redux store to track them so that you don't lose the original users field**

```
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    users: [],
    filteredUsers: [],
    isLoading: true,
    search: "",
  },
  reducers: {
    usersSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.users = action.payload;
      state.isLoading = false;
    searchByName: (state, action) => {

      return {
        ...state,
        filteredUsers: [...state.users].filter((user) => user.name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase()))
     };

    },
  },
});
```

Use one or the other, not both solutions!

---

Edit: #2 Here's a full working solution Solution #2 (https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-estrela-b6o5p3?file=/src/index.js:211-1748)

```
const users = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    users: [{ name: "aldo" }, { name: "kiv" }],
    filteredUsers: [{ name: "aldo" }, { name: "kiv" }],
    isLoading: true,
    search: ""
  },
  reducers: {
    usersSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.users = action.payload;
      state.isLoading = false;
      return {
        users: action.payload,
        filteredUsers: [...action.payload],
        isLoading: false
      };
    },
    searchByName: (state, action) => {
      const filteredUsers = state.users.filter((user) =>
        user.name.toLowerCase().includes(action.payload.toLowerCase())
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredUsers:
          action.payload.length > 0 ? filteredUsers : [...state.users]
      };
    }
  }
});

const userActions = users.actions;

// store
var store = createStore(users.reducer);

// component
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const filteredUsers = useSelector((state) => state.filteredUsers);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  console.log(users);

  const changeSearchTerm = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userActions.searchByName(searchTerm));
  }, [searchTerm, dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={changeSearchTerm} type="text" value={searchTerm} />
      <div>
        {filteredUsers.map((user) => (
          <div>{user.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// --root store config
const store = createStore(users.reducer);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your brief answer. However, I have a question. if I want to remove a user from the filteredUsers, how can I do this? something like     onRemove(state, { payload }) {
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredUsers: [...state.Users].filter((user) => user.id !== payload),
      };
    },

as reducer will do the work?

Comment: That approach seems reasonable. In general though, you should think of `filteredUsers` as a readonly variable that you're only setting to provide a "view" of the actual users data. So wherever/whenever you update the original `users` list OR you need to apply some search/filter criteria, that's when you should modify `filteredUsers`. 

In this case if you're adding a functionality where someone can "hide" a user from the view, then yes what you suggested should work.

Comment: @Azarro Thank you very well you showed and explained