# How to show or hide my subcategory depend click on main category using react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

How to write  action logic for show and hide  element. Right now my all subcategory  showing but I want to show theme after user click on manin category. Assume user click on electronic category so it should be open only all sub-category of electronic. If user click on another main category then previous main category should be hide.  here is my code:.

```
export const adsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ads_category",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // setProducts(state, action) {
    //     state.data = action.payload;
    // },
    // setStatus(state, action) {
    //     state.status = action.payload;
    // },
},
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
        .addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = STATUSES.LOADING;
        })
        .addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.data = action.payload;
            state.status = STATUSES.IDLE;
        })
        .addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = STATUSES.ERROR;
        });
},
})
```

my  page

```
const PostAds = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const display_category = useSelector(state=>state.ads)
  

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  
}, []);

 

  
    return (
      <>.....</>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create boolean state for all of your sub-categories then create a function that has a parameter of category then switch cases which state will be true. Here's a sample code for implementation.

```
const [isMainCategory, setIsMainCategory] = useState(false)
const [isElectornics, setIsElectronics] = useState(false)

function handleShow(category){
    switch(category)
       case 'main-category':
           setIsMainCategory(true)
           setIsElectronics(false)
           break
       case 'electronics':
           setIsMainCategory(false)
           setIsElectronics(true)
           break
      default:
           setIsMainCategory(false)
           setIsElectronics(false)
          
}

return (
  <button onClick={() => handleShow('main-category')}>Main</button>
  <button onClick={() => handleShow('electronics')>Electronics</button>

  // this syntax here will check if your logic is true your component will show
  {isMainCategory && `your main category component`}
  {isElectrocnics && ` you electronics category component}
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answare but in real project I have too many category so it will be not possible for me to define all category one by one.

Comment: If your data had an identifier which category then you can create a function that will fitler the data by identifier

Comment: Marvin Roque yes  my each category have identifier which is id. can u show an example?

Comment: For your reference maybe you could check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72164352/redux-toolkit-trying-to-use-filter-in-a-reducer-function-but-it-doesnt-behave